# Не могу понять принцип работы кода, Треугольник Серпинского

Tags: java

Не могу понять по какому принципу работает этот код. Это первая часть кода:

```
    * @author ZTILabPI  */ public class Main {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            TurtleAlgorithms alg = new TurtleAlgorithms();
            alg.positioningTurtle(30); 
//        alg. sierpinski(bok, minBok);
            alg.sierpinski(200, 50); 
//        alg.callSnowFlake(3, 400); 
//        alg.snowFlake(3, 400);
        }
     }
```

Это вторая часть кода:

```
package Turtle;


import turtlePck.TurtleGraphicsWindow;



/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author ZTILabPI
 */
public class TurtleAlgorithms extends TurtleGraphicsWindow{

    public void positioningTurtle(int angle){
        right(angle);
    }


    public void sierpinski(int bok, int minBok ){
         if (bok<minBok) {
            return;
        }
          for(int i=1;i<4;i++){
              sierpinski(bok/2, minBok);
              forward(bok);
              right(120);
          }
      }

}
```

Получается, этот код работает, он рисует треугольник Серпинского, но я не могу понять по какому принципу.

Comment: поизменяй разные параметры, смотри что получается

Comment: @Миша Котор Да я уже так делал, и постепенно применять пытался, но всеравно какой-то бред получается, а мне для вуза нужно нарисовать определённую фигуру. А без понимания принципа работы кода мне этого не удастся сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что сделает процедура  `sierpinski`, если из неё убрать рекурсивный вызов?

Она с помощью черепашьих методов нарисует равносторонний треугольник со стороной `bok`. Это понятно?

А что делает рекурсивный вызов? Он в каждой вершине рисует треугольник вдвое меньше.

А что делает рекурсивный вызов внутри рекурсивного вызова? Он в каждой вершине половинного треугольника рисует треугольник размеров в четверть.

И так продолжается до тех пор, пока размер не станет слишком мал (срабатывает условие останова рекурсии).

В каком порядке треугольники рисуются? Сначала самый маленький внутри первой вершины. Потом сторона треугольника чуть больше. Потом опять самый маленький, потом сторона побольше, опять маленький, и завершение треугольника побольше, потом сторона третьего с конца и т.д.
Этот порядок (хотя бы размер) стоит вывести в консоль или текстовое окно (что там у Вас доступно), чтобы лучше разобраться, как работает рекурсия.

Comment: Что такое отладочная распечатка?

Comment: @Anton Sorokin Отладочная печать - вывод текста, значений переменных  в консоль, текстовое окно, в файл. Термин неудачный?

Comment: даже не знаю. По "отладочная распечатка" гугл утром не выдал ничего, по "отладочная печать" - выдал инфу. Т.е. вроде норм. С другой стороны, он нигде не используется, и я бы без гугла не понял что это(а новички в гугл не лезут).

Comment: @Anton Sorokin ОК, переформулировал.

Comment: @MBo А как вывести в консоль в NetBeans, данные которые мне доступны?

Comment: @BraFik Когда я пишу в ideone или другой онлайн-оболочке, то использую `System.out.println`